# Converting to PDF: Ruby on Rails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to have a particular page render to PDF. My app is written in Ruby on Rails and hosted on Heroku.

For development, I'm on Mac OS X. I'm using wicked_pdf (that uses the wkhtmltopdf) to convert the page to pdf. I have it setup properly on Heroku as well, but the issue I'm facing is that the rendered PDF looks pretty significantly different on OS X when compared to Heroku: most of the CSS simply doesn't work.

1) Has anyone done html to pdf operations on Heroku? If so, what did you use?

2) Any idea why the rendering on the Mac is different than on Linux?

Thanks!
Ringo

Answer (score 0):

I use prawnPDF (http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/), but this doesn't fit your html->PDF case. But one of the issues can be what fonts are supported on Mac vs Heroku, which can cause rendering issues, this may be relevant.